# I am trying to create an interactive Treemap in R, using plotly and all im getting as an output is a blank chart (new to R)

Tags: r, plotly, treemap

Code below is what I have, I just can't seem to get it to be nested by Countries

```r
# URL of the dataset(s)
url_1 <- "https://api.iea.org/methane/comparison?source=IEA&csv=true"


# Read the data from the URL into a data frame called CH4
CH4 <- read_csv(url_1)

BRICS <- CH4 %>%
  filter(segment != "Total") %>%
  filter(country %in% c("Brazil", "Russia", "India", "China", "South Africa"))%>%
  select(-region,-source,-reason,-notes,-baseYear,-type)%>%
  mutate(emissions_rounded = signif(emissions, digits = 3))

# Create a color palette for the unique segments
unique_segments <- unique(BRICS$segment)
colors <- brewer.pal(length(unique_segments), "Set3")
color_map <- setNames(colors, unique_segments)

plot_ly(
  data = BRICS,
  type = "treemap",
  ids = ~paste(country, segment),
  labels = ~country,
  parents = ~"",
  values = ~emissions_rounded,
  customdata = ~segment,
  hoverinfo = "text",
  hovertemplate = "<b>%{label}</b><br>Segment: %{customdata}<br>Emissions: %{value}<extra></extra>",
  textposition = "inside",
  insidetextanchor = "middle",
  textfont = list(size = 14),
  marker = list(
    colors = ~color_map[segment],
    colorscale = "identity",
    showscale = TRUE,
    colorbar = list(title = "Segment")
  )
) %>%
  layout(title = "BRICS Methane Emissions Treemap Chart")
```

I was playing around with labels and parents, to see if there was an issue with that but just made it blank, I'm (somewhat) sure that my data frame is correct

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to make this work, but Plotly is particularly painful when it comes to this type of plot.

In my answer, I've modified your data.

- grouped by country and segment and summed the emissions (you may have wanted the average, median, or something else here)
- added the unique country names to the segment column (this creates country 'containers')
- added the `ids` column-- this has to be the first column in the dataset...don't ask me why...it just *is* required by Plotly (sigh)

This code is built on top of your original code, it comes *after* you create `color_map`. *After I initially create the plot, I go into more detail regarding the colors.*

###### Group and consolidate by country/segment

```
BRICS1 <- BRICS %>% group_by(country, segment) %>% 
  summarise(emissions = sum(emissions)) %>% 
  mutate(emissions_rounded = round(emissions, 1)) # re-create rounded values
```

###### Add rows where countries are entered in the segments column

This is how you create a parent "container".

```
lapply(unique(BRICS1$country), function(j) {
  ems <- sum(BRICS1[BRICS1$country == j, ]$emissions)
  BRICS1[nrow(BRICS1) + 1, ] <<- list("", j, ems, round(ems, 1))
})

tail(BRICS1 %>% as.data.frame()) # inspect for expected
#         country      segment emissions emissions_rounded
# 51 South Africa   Steam coal  1060.310            1060.3
# 52                    Brazil  1756.495            1756.5
# 53                     China 25372.222           25372.2
# 54                     India  5185.236            5185.2
# 55                    Russia 18078.084           18078.1
# 56              South Africa  1239.030            1239.0
```

###### Add `ids` column to data frame

This ensures that the parent and the child remain connected.

```
BRICS1 <- BRICS1 %>%        # if country container, ids == country name
  mutate(ids = ifelse(country == "", segment, paste0(country, "_", segment))) %>% 
  select(ids, everything()) # ensure ids is the first column (make plotly :)
```

###### The plot

Now the plot...you aren't going to be able to make a discrete color into a `colorbar` without a lot of finesse/manipulation. With the number of unique colors you have, this would be an *excessive* amount of manipulation. Instead of removing that code, I've commented it out.

```
plot_ly(type = "treemap", data = BRICS1, labels = ~segment, parents = ~country,
        ids = ~ids, values = ~emissions_rounded, hoverinfo = "text",
        hovertemplate = "<b>%{parent}</b><br>Segment: %{label}<br>Emissions: %{value}<extra></extra>",
        textposition = "inside", insidetextanchor = "middle",
        textfont = list(size = 14),
        marker = list(
          colors = ~color_map[segment]
          # colorscale = "identity",
          # showscale = TRUE
          # colorbar = list(title = "Segment")
        )) %>%
  layout(title = "BRICS Methane Emissions Treemap Chart")
```

This is what you get.

[image]

##### Changing the color map to include country backgrounds

The colors of the country backgrounds look pretty awful compared to the rest of the color scheme.

> To get these on the same color scheme, you can create the colors list after the data changes. Alternatively, you could append a named vector to the existing colormap.

Here's an example of how you could append the country labels to the existing `color_map`:

```
# note that BRICS is used, not BRICS1 (there is a country == "" in BRICKS1)
cty <- setNames(rep("black", length(unique(BRICS$country))), unique(BRICS$country))
color_map2 <- c(color_map, cty)  # append to colormap

plot_ly(type = "treemap", data = BRICS1, labels = ~segment, parents = ~country,
        ids = ~ids, values = ~emissions_rounded, hoverinfo = "text",
        hovertemplate = "<b>%{parent}</b><br>Segment: %{label}<br>Emissions: %{value}<extra></extra>",
        textposition = "inside", insidetextanchor = "middle",
        textfont = list(size = 14),
        marker = list(
          colors = ~color_map2[segment]             ### <----- using new color_map
        )) %>%
  layout(title = "BRICS Methane Emissions Treemap Chart")
```

[image]

If you click in the blank area of any of the country containers, you will drill down so that you can read more details.

[image]

##### All the code altogether (to make this easier to copy and paste)

This includes making the countries' backgrounds black.

```
# your code is unchanged in these first three function calls

# URL of the dataset(s)
url_1 <- "https://api.iea.org/methane/comparison?source=IEA&csv=true"

# Read the data from the URL into a data frame called CH4
CH4 <- read_csv(url_1)

BRICS <- CH4 %>%
  filter(segment != "Total") %>%
  filter(country %in% c("Brazil", "Russia", "India", "China", "South Africa"))%>%
  select(-region,-source,-reason,-notes,-baseYear,-type)%>%
  mutate(emissions_rounded = signif(emissions, digits = 3))

# Create a color palette for the unique segments
unique_segments <- unique(BRICS$segment)
colors <- brewer.pal(length(unique_segments), "Set3")
color_map <- setNames(colors, unique_segments)

#-------- the remaining code is from this answer ----------

BRICS1 <- BRICS %>% group_by(country, segment) %>% 
  summarise(emissions = sum(emissions)) %>% 
  mutate(emissions_rounded = round(emissions, 1)) # re-create rounded values

# create container rows
lapply(unique(BRICS1$country), function(j) {
  ems <- sum(BRICS1[BRICS1$country == j, ]$emissions)
  BRICS1[nrow(BRICS1) + 1, ] <<- list("", j, ems, round(ems, 1))
})

tail(BRICS1 %>% as.data.frame()) # inspect for expected
#         country      segment emissions emissions_rounded
# 51 South Africa   Steam coal  1060.310            1060.3
# 52                    Brazil  1756.495            1756.5
# 53                     China 25372.222           25372.2
# 54                     India  5185.236            5185.2
# 55                    Russia 18078.084           18078.1
# 56              South Africa  1239.030            1239.0 

BRICS1 <- BRICS1 %>%        # if country container, ids == country name
  mutate(ids = ifelse(country == "", segment, paste0(country, "_", segment))) %>% 
  select(ids, everything()) # ensure ids is the first column (make plotly :)

# using BRICS, not BRICS1 due to "" country
cty <- setNames(rep("black", length(unique(BRICS$country))), unique(BRICS$country))
color_map2 <- c(color_map, cty)  # append to colormap

plot_ly(type = "treemap", data = BRICS1, labels = ~segment, parents = ~country,
        ids = ~ids, values = ~emissions_rounded, hoverinfo = "text",
        hovertemplate = "<b>%{parent}</b><br>Segment: %{label}<br>Emissions: %{value}<extra></extra>",
        textposition = "inside", insidetextanchor = "middle",
        textfont = list(size = 14),
        marker = list(
          colors = ~color_map2[segment]             ### <----- using new color_map
        )) %>%
  layout(title = "BRICS Methane Emissions Treemap Chart")
```